# Proper way to store and pass username and password to config for database connection?

Tags: reactjs, express, security, backend, tedious

I have just created my first React back-end using Express and Tedious. What is the proper way to store and/or pass in the Username and Password to connect to the database? Is the 'back-end' secure enough to have it in-line like this?

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/dbCall', (req, res) => {
    var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
    var Request = require('tedious').Request;
    var config = {
        "server": "localhost",
        "authentication": {
          "type": "default",
          "options": {
            "userName": "myUsername",
            "password": "myPassword"
          }
        },
        "options": {
          "port": 1533,
          "database": "myDB",
        }
      }
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to store your 'secret' data is to use the [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) module.

**1. Install the module:**

```
npm install dotenv
```

**2. Create the ".env" file in your root directory (same directory as package.json)**

Content of your .env should look like this (yeah, it's just plain text):

```
APP_SERVER=localhost
APP_USERNAME=myUsername
APP_PASSWORD=myPassword
APP_PORT=1533
APP_DATABASE=myDB
```

**3. Setup dotenv (You want to do this as early as possible in your application)**

```
// example where to put it
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();
```

**4. Profit**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();

app.get('/dbCall', (req, res) => {
    var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
    var Request = require('tedious').Request;
    var config = {
        "server": process.env.APP_SERVER,
        "authentication": {
          "type": "default",
          "options": {
            "userName": process.env.APP_USERNAME,
            "password": process.env.APP_PASSWORD
          }
        },
        "options": {
          "port": process.env.APP_PORT,
          "database": process.env.APP_DATABASE,
        }
      }
  }
```

**Note:**
If you're using git you have to put the ".env" file in your [.gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) and you might want to consider deleting previous commits if you've already pushed your secret data.

**EDIT:**
If you're using the database config object multiple times, I'd recommend putting your config in a separate file.

1. create "databaseConfig.js" file

```js
module.exports = {
  server: process.env.APP_SERVER,
  authentication: {
    type: "default",
    options: {
      userName: process.env.APP_USERNAME,
      password: process.env.APP_PASSWORD
    }
  },
  options: {
    port: process.env.APP_PORT,
    database: process.env.APP_DATABASE
  }
}
```

2. require "databaseConfig.js" in your code

```js
const config = require("path/to/databaseConfig.js");
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the concise answer. Worked 100%. If I could give you an award or medal, I would.